# JavaScript function to extract all strings inside an object and all its children

Tags: javascript

I want to build a function that can get all strings from an object and all its children.

Number of children is unknown. Also, it can be an object or an array. or even an object of arrays.

I built one with recursion but I ended up just getting the first string in the object or its children. Whenever the function finds a string, it stops and never call again!

```js
const findErrorString = (error) => {
  switch (errors.constructor) {
    case String:
      return error;
    case Object:
      const childError = Object.keys(errors).map((key) => {
        return error[key];
      });

      return findErrorString(childError);
    case Array:
      const childError = error.map((item) => {
        return item;
      });

      return findErrorString(childError);

    default:
      return "Oh i didn't find any error.";
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the function below

```
const findErrorsString = (errors) => {
  switch (errors.constructor) {
    case String:
      return errors;
    case Object:
      let objChildError = Object.keys(errors).map((key) => errors[key]);
      return objChildError.map(findErrorsString);
    case Array:
      return errors.map(findErrorsString);

    default:
      return "Oh i didn't find any error.";
  }
};
```

Calling

> findErrorsString({'a': [{'b' : 'c'}], 'd': 'e', 'w': {'q': 'r'}}).flat(5)

would return

> ["c", "e", "r"]

which are the leaf strings in the whole object. `flat(5)` indicates the max depth to which array should be flattened.`

Answer (score 5):

Something like that should work:

```
const getAllStrings = (arg) => {
  if (typeof arg === "string") {
    return [arg];
  }

  // handle wrong types and null
  if (typeof arg !== "object" || !arg) {
    return [];
  }

  return Object.keys(arg).reduce((acc, key) => {
    return [...acc, ...getAllStrings(arg[key])];
  }, []);
};

console.log(getAllStrings({
  foo: ["str", "str2"],
  bar: {
    abc: "str3",
    def: ["str4"],
    ijk: {
      a3: "str5",
    }
  },
})); // ['str, 'str2', 'str3', 'str4', 'str5']
```